# Prove/disprove that $A$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: calculus, general-topology

My question is: Define $r(\theta,\phi)=(\cos(\phi)\sin(\theta),\sin(\phi)\sin(\theta),\cos(\theta)$ and denote $A=\{r(\theta,\phi):\theta \in (0,\pi), ~\phi \in (0,\pi)\} \}$.

> Prove or disprove: A is open in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

I'm not certain how to show that A is open with polar coordinates. I will greatly appreciate an explanation on the mindset of how to show such things with polar coordinates(or an explanation why it is not open if that is the answer)

Comment: Please use *MathJax* so others can search and find your question.

Comment: What is your definition of *"open"*?

Comment: Also, related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3587948/impossible-problem-to-solve-manually/3588007?noredirect=1#comment7377054_3588007

Comment: My definition is: A subset of R^n is an open set if for every x that belongs to A there exists r>0 such that B(x,r) a subset of A

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that the set A is just the set of points on a unit sphere centered at the origin. To see why, $\theta$ can be interpreted to be the elevation angle and $\phi$ azimuth angle. Can you now complete the problem? Is the set of the points on a unit sphere an open set?

Hint: Take any point on the unit sphere and draw another sphere around it with that chosen point as its center. That is your ball $B$. Then, go back to the definition.

if you are new to polar coordinates, please see -

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system

Comment: thanks a lot, this really helps me to visualize it, I am a little new to using topology this way and because of quarantine in my country I need to mostly learn this things alone which makes it a little hard. I will try to understand it with what you wrote

Comment: Sure, in this case I will help you this time. Basically no matter how small a ball you draw around any chosen point on the unit sphere, no matter how small the radius you choose it will ALWAYS have points (in $\mathbb{R}^3$) that are not on the unit sphere. Thus, the defitinition is violated as there does not exists such a $r$. (Only $r=0$ works but the definition requires $r>0$)

Comment: @IdanDaniel Do accept my answer if you are satisfied. Will be grateful

Comment: Just did. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

$A$ isn't open.  It's a subset of $S^2$, which doesn't contain any open sets.  That is, $S^2$ is *nowhere dense*.

Comment: Excuse my daftness but could you define $S$?

Comment: Sure.  It's the unit sphere.

Comment: If $S=[0,1]$, why doesn’t it contain open sets? Wouldn’t $(1/3,1/2) \subset S$ be open?

Comment: Intuitively, it's a closed $2$-dimensional submanifold of $\Bbb R^3$. Because of the lower dimension, it has no interior.  From your standpoint, you may just note that any open set in $\Bbb R^3$ contains points outside the sphere.  You could use the metric, say, to prove it.

Comment: Wait a minute.  We're in $\Bbb R^3$.  And $S^2$ is the set of points at distance $1$ from the origin.

Comment: Again, intuitively, $S^2$ is sort of "too thin" to contain an open set.

Comment: Thank you, that clarifies it and makes sense! I was wrongly thinking about $S^2$ containing sets that are open in itself and was confused. Your statement is about openness in $\mathbb{R}^3$.